# On Target Unit testing for STM32L0x3 using IAR

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, stm32, iar

I want to have a test frame work in my IAR Project. The processor is an STM32L0.

What I've tried:

- https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest followed the turoial at : https://cpputest.github.io/stories.html
  Didn't work because there is only 64K Flash & 8K RAM

  [image]

  and its not enough for this framework
- https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity.git I tried to intigrate into IAR Embedded workbench but had a lot of compiler errors also not enough space so I tried to run it on my Desktop. This doesn't work because it has too many Hardware dependencies in the code..
- Next I tried to just make "Pseudo" unit testing by putting a test routine at boot of the device which can be switched on and off by precompiler directives.

Like this (not finished):

```
#if PREFORM_TESTS
    TEST_run();
#endif
```

And then with files:

```
#include "testAll.h"
#include "testEvent.h"
#include "stm32l0xx_hal.h"

void TEST_run(){
  TEST_EVENT_run();
}
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line){
  while(1);  
}

#include "testEvent.h"
#include "testAll.h"
#include "event.h"
#include "stm32l0xx_hal.h"

void test_add_event();

void TEST_EVENT_run(){
    test_add_event();
}

void test_add_event(){
  ASSERT(1); 
}
```

How can I run Unit Tests on my STM32L0x3?

Comment: IAR EWARM has an ARM simulator. This combined with some CSPY macros and breakpoints and you can further simulate hardware, and implement unit tests. I believe they have a way to call C functions from the CSPY macros, but I may be mistaken (don't have the manual handy).

Answer (score 2):

Generally for even embedded targets, code 'modules' are compiled on your desktop target. So you would pull in the modules into your tests and stub out/mock hardware specific ones.

If there isn't enough space for putting a testing framework on the device, then perhaps you shouldn't (or find a more minimal one). You will then have to write your tests in the application code without a testing framework, just as if you would write normal application code.